# SP Initiated C# SAML

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, saml

We have Service Provider which requires SAML assertion to be done by SP Initiated. We need to enable our web application which is ASP.Net MVC C#
to perform SP -Initiated SSO. The flow which we are looking at is

***Web Application -> Clicks Link to access Resource -> Goes to SP -> SP Redirects to IDP(i.e. our Web Application) -> Validate the User-> HTTP POST-> Access SP Site***

Can we stimulate this flow from c# code,the challenge we are facing is how to relay state back to SP when we validate the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you roll your own.

Rather implement a SAML stack.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Comment: Any example do you have as a reference?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43 A lot of these have examples in the docs.

Comment: sorry I am not able to find SP initiated login it's just Idp Login is there

Comment: Most (if not all) of them support SP Initiated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the SAML standards. In there you need to setup assertion consumer service, which is callig from IDP once the user get validated and authenticated.

Comment: Any example do you have as reference?